# What happens when TestFlight app expire?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm using the prerelease tool in iTunesConnect where you can distribute the app to a group of testers. It seems though that after some days the app crashes immediately after start (just after the splash screen shown). No error logs.

I'm wondering if this has to do with the 30days expiration that all TestFlight apps seems to have, or maybe it's something in my code that causing it?

Comment: I would not say it's crashing. It has no valid certificate and refuses to be executed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next time a user attempts to launch the beta app, they will get a dialog box saying `"YOURAPPNAME" Beta Has Expired`, and the app will not launch.

The app should not crash (nor run), as your question describes.

Answer (score 20):

You're absolutely right, Toydor!

After the 30-days-period expired, your test won't be able download or run your app.
I didn't find a way to extend this period. You only can upload an updated version to get another 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do to identify this:

1. Get the app on a device, run the app, then check if the device has a crash report by e.g. using Xcode. If there is a crash report, check it. in addition check the console output on the device when the "crash" happens.
2. Check the iTunes Connect website and navigate to the specific build. Check if the page shows some status as "expired" for that build.

Comment: 1. I double-checked the device logs from XCode, but there was no logs about the crash. 
2. The build was in inactive state in IC, but should the installed build be crashing for me even if its inactive and expired?

Comment: Check the device console output. That should give you an idea. If an prov. profile is expired, the app will not start. And iTunes Connect builds are only running for 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why app cannot execute is that no valid provisioning profile was found.

And we can find those logs in device console output:

```
Mar  9 08:34:48 ***-iPhone amfid[***] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar  9 08:34:48 ***-iPhone amfid[***] <Error>: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B4BF7C1D-2DF4-4B8D-943B-57BABD30****/***.app/*** not valid: 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
Mar  9 08:34:48 ***-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: hook..execve() killing pid 10282: no code signature
Mar  9 08:34:48 ***-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: hook..execve() killing pid 10282: application requires container but none set
Mar  9 08:34:48 ***-iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.***.***[0x4711][10282]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
```

Comment: I think this is actually an attempt to answer, by describing the messages found in error logs when a TestFlight app expires.